# How to send a console command to a webpage in JS?

Tags: javascript, chat, bots, greasemonkey, chatbot

I'm trying to submit a message into a chatroom via Greasemonkey for Firefox. There is no button on the webpage, the message must be sent with the enter key. Inspecting the chat input field, this appears:

`<input type="text" id="chatcli" placeholder="type chat message here" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13) ChatClient.sendLine();">`

I'm able to edit the text box using `document.getElementById('chatcli').value = "/bot command here"+x`, but can't figure out how to actually send it.

I noticed that if I type `ChatClient.sendLine();` into the console, the message sends. I tried putting that code in my Greasemonkey script, but it didn't work. I also tried `document.ChatClient.sendLine();`, nothing.

There must be a way to send console commands to the webpage. What am I missing?
If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you're running in the sandbox, explicitly reference the window variable: `window.ChatClient.sendLine()` (or `unsafeWindow.ChatClient.sendLine()`, not sure which is needed), or inject the code into the DOM, or disable the sandbox, one of those will probably work

Comment: `unsafeWindow.ChatClient.sendLine()` worked. Thank you! @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch a keyboard event with the right `keyCode`.

```js
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var input = document.querySelector("#chatcli");
  input.value = "/bot command here";
  input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'keyCode':13}));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="chatcli" placeholder="type chat message here" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13) console.log('enter pressed. textbox value:' + this.value);">

<button id="btn">click me to test</button>
```